# How to create dynamic LINQ Expression with multiple binary expression conditions and a contains condition

Tags: linq, dynamic, expression, linq-expressions, dynamic-linq

I want to create a dynamic LINQ Expression for this kind of query

```cs
people.Where(x => x.Name="Some_Name" && x.Age>60 && x.ChildIds.Contains("Some_Id"));
```

What I have already done is populating my `List<BinaryExpression>`. The `List<BinaryExpression>` contains the `x.Name="Some_Name"` and `x.Age>60`.

My problem is now with the `x.ChildIds.Contains("Some_Id")`. What I was looking for a way to dynamically create the `Contains` expression, this iswhat I got:

```cs
Expression.Call(memberExpression, "Contains", null, constantExpression)
```

But this returns a `MethodCallExpression` and I couldn't append to my `List<BinaryExpression>`

The reason why I want to append the `contains` expression into the `BinaryExpression` is because this is how I do the `&&` part of the LINQ

```cs
var aggregatedExpressions = binaryExpressions.Aggregate((x, y) => Expression.AndAlso(x, y));
```

If there's no way for me to append the Contains expression into the Binary Expression, how do I aggregate the Contains `MethodCallExpression` into my `aggregatedExpressions` so it would be written  in this way?

```cs
x.Name="Some_Name" && x.Age>60 && x.ChildIds.Contains("Some_Id")
```

Comment: You could change the `List<BinaryExpression>` to `List<Expression>` since `BinaryExpression` is just a subset of boolean expressions that can be aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this now. I've figure out how I'll aggregate the `MethodCallExpressions`

```cs
aggregatedExpressions = Expression.AndAlso(aggregatedExpressions, methodCallExpression);
```